# Is there any way to incease emgu haarcascade square size while detecting face?

Tags: c#, emgucv, windows, face-detection, haar-classifier

I am using the below code to capture the face http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real. its working as i expected. but i wanted to increase height and weight of detected area.

[image]

The below is sample code:

```
public partial class FrmPrincipal : Form
{
    //Declararation of all variables, vectors and haarcascades
    Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame;
    Capture grabber;
    HaarCascade face;
    HaarCascade eye;
    MCvFont font = new MCvFont(FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5d, 0.5d);
    Image<Gray, byte> result, TrainedFace = null;
    Image<Gray, byte> gray = null;
    List<Image<Gray, byte>> trainingImages = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
    List<string> labels= new List<string>();
    List<string> NamePersons = new List<string>();
    int ContTrain, NumLabels, t;
    string name, names = null;


    public FrmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Load haarcascades for face detection
        face = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        //eye = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_eye.xml");
        try
        {
            //Load of previus trainned faces and labels for each image
            string Labelsinfo = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt");
            string[] Labels = Labelsinfo.Split('%');
            NumLabels = Convert.ToInt16(Labels[0]);
            ContTrain = NumLabels;
            string LoadFaces;

            for (int tf = 1; tf < NumLabels+1; tf++)
            {
                LoadFaces = "face" + tf + ".bmp";
                trainingImages.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + LoadFaces));
                labels.Add(Labels[tf]);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing in binary database, please add at least a face(Simply train the prototype with the Add Face Button).", "Triained faces load", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Initialize the capture device
        grabber = new Capture();
        grabber.QueryFrame();
        //Initialize the FrameGraber event
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Trained face counter
            ContTrain = ContTrain + 1;

            //Get a gray frame from capture device
            gray = grabber.QueryGrayFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

            //Face Detector
            MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
            face,
            1.2,
            10,
            Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
            new Size(20, 20));

            //Action for each element detected
            foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
            {
                TrainedFace = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>();
                break;
            }

            //resize face detected image for force to compare the same size with the 
            //test image with cubic interpolation type method
            TrainedFace = result.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            trainingImages.Add(TrainedFace);
            labels.Add(textBox1.Text);

            //Show face added in gray scale
            imageBox1.Image = TrainedFace;

            //Write the number of triained faces in a file text for further load
            File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt", trainingImages.ToArray().Length.ToString() + "%");

            //Write the labels of triained faces in a file text for further load
            for (int i = 1; i < trainingImages.ToArray().Length + 1; i++)
            {
                trainingImages.ToArray()[i - 1].Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/face" + i + ".bmp");
                File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt", labels.ToArray()[i - 1] + "%");
            }

            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + "´s face detected and added :)", "Training OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enable the face detection first", "Training Fail", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }


    void FrameGrabber(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label3.Text = "0";
        //label4.Text = "";
        NamePersons.Add("");


        //Get the current frame form capture device
        currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

                //Convert it to Grayscale
                gray = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                //Face Detector
                MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
              face,
              1.4,
              10,
              Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
              new Size(20, 20));

                //Action for each element detected
                foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
                {
                    t = t + 1;
                    result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                    //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
                    currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);


                    if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
                    {
                        //TermCriteria for face recognition with numbers of trained images like maxIteration
                    MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001);

                    //Eigen face recognizer
                    EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
                       trainingImages.ToArray(),
                       labels.ToArray(),
                       3000,
                       ref termCrit);

                    name = recognizer.Recognize(result);

                        //Draw the label for each face detected and recognized
                    currentFrame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));

                    }

                        NamePersons[t-1] = name;
                        NamePersons.Add("");


                    //Set the number of faces detected on the scene
                    label3.Text = facesDetected[0].Length.ToString();

                    /*
                    //Set the region of interest on the faces

                    gray.ROI = f.rect;
                    MCvAvgComp[][] eyesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
                       eye,
                       1.1,
                       10,
                       Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                       new Size(20, 20));
                    gray.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                    foreach (MCvAvgComp ey in eyesDetected[0])
                    {
                        Rectangle eyeRect = ey.rect;
                        eyeRect.Offset(f.rect.X, f.rect.Y);
                        currentFrame.Draw(eyeRect, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
                    }
                     */

                }
                    t = 0;

                    //Names concatenation of persons recognized
                for (int nnn = 0; nnn < facesDetected[0].Length; nnn++)
                {
                    names = names + NamePersons[nnn] + ", ";
                }
                //Show the faces procesed and recognized
                imageBoxFrameGrabber.Image = currentFrame;
                label4.Text = names;
                names = "";
                //Clear the list(vector) of names
                NamePersons.Clear();

            }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("Donate.html");
    }
```

Suggest me for the best solution. If not What is the other way to do it?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you even read the code? its pretty clear which parts of the code have to do with sizing

Comment: @Sayse can you please guide me which part of code will do this?

Comment: Press ctrl+f and type "size"

Comment: I have tried changing to new Size(30, 30). but i m getting the same result.

Comment: let me know the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Rather trivial, but need to understand the code
After you get the result in variable "f", you should change this line

```
currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
```

to draw the new rectangle according to the position of the detected one. Note that the result doesn't change, you change only what you show the user.
So it should be somewhat like that:

```
                    Rectangle newFaceRect = new Rectangle();
                    newFaceRect.Location = f.Location;
                    newFaceRect.Y = (int)(f.Y - face.Height / 4);
                    newFaceRect.X = (int)(f.X - face.Width / 4);
                    newFaceRect.Height = (int)(f.Height * 1.5);
                    newFaceRect.Width = (int)(f.Width * 1.5);
                    currentFrame.Draw(newFaceRect, new Bgr(Color.Black), 2);
```